# AADSTS70005: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

> AADSTS70005: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the
>   application

I am getting above error even after setting `"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true`, in manifest.

Comment: You could try to manually adding "groupMembershipClaims": null to the manifest.

Comment: Sometimes caching can affect things, have you tried again?

Comment: Do you have any process on this case?

Comment: Can you add more information such as - what platform is your app, if your app is a 'converged app' created in apps.dev.microsoft.com or a Azure AD app created in portal.azure.com. Also it would be helpful to have some source code on how you are requesting the token. I've seen this error happening when you don't have a RedirectURL on your app.

Comment: Same problem here, I'm trying to implement OpenID 1.0 authentication flow in PHP. Neither the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` nor the `groupMembershipClaims` work for me. I'd really like to give up Azure AD forever, if only I were allowed to.

Comment: I am getting "AADSTS700051: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application." error

Comment: I believe there might be a delay / caching issue going on here. Take your time (a few minutes)  before testing any changes to App registrations

Answer (score 168):

try this:
go to portal.azure.com
select your directory, and go to Azure AD
then select App registration (preview)
select the app you are trying to authenticate (you should already have registered it)
go to the authentication tab
check "ID tokens" in the Advanced Settings section (see the bottom of the attached image)

[image]

this have worked for me

Comment: can we authorize an azure function using this technique ?

Comment: I also had to check the "Access tokens" box too before the error would go away.

Comment: Note that the UI has changed. This setting is no longer under "Advanced Settings", the checkbox is now under "Implicit grant and hybrid flows".

Answer (score 33):

I got the error:

> AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.

And the resolution was setting:

```js
{
  "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" : true
}
```

in Azure Active Directory [App Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest)

Comment: If you are using the "new experience" in the Azure Portal, you will set this flag in the `Manifest` area.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you have selected `ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)`
You can do from `Authentication` blade in your app in Azure AD. See screenshot below
[image]

Or go to the `Manifest` blade and make `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` to `true`. See screenshot below
[image]

Comment: After making oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow to true, I am getting error as "AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application."

Answer (score 9):

**Error : OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'unsupported_response_type'.** 
This error occurred because Azure AD not return any Access tokens or ID tokens.
Azure AD need to enabled check box to return tokens, after authentication is done.

**How to Solve :** goto Azure AD => App registration => click tab Authentication =>
enabled Access tokens and ID tokens check-boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have two instances of the key `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` in your manifest - in my case I had added the key but it was present already with the value set to false. Hopefully this solves the issue:)

Comment: can we authorize an azure function using this technique ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue and when visited the page of ActiveDirectory -> App registrations, it wasnt showing new UI.

Also it doesnt allow me to set the flag in the metadata, Found the workaround for this.

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/Authentication/quickStartType//sourceType/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/appId/9bab1d75-34b8-475b-abfe-5a62c6f01234/objectId/a4b459c1-7753-400c-8f8f-46fb5451234/isMSAApp//defaultBlade/Overview/servicePrincipalCreated/true

First login to your instance, modify the above URL to paste object id and application id of your application.

Then it should show the screen @Mosè Bottacini posted.

Answer (score 1):

It is true like a lot of you are saying that you need to enable `ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)` if you really need the ID Token.

> 'AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the
> application.

However if you use a `Authorization Code Flow` you don't really need it. Microsoft OpenID Connect authentication (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`) uses `id_token` as default `ResponseType` for `OpenIdConnect` and `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.

[image]

Using `AddOpenIdConnect` you can set `ResponseType` to `OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code` or simply `"code"` and then you don't need the `id_token` at all.

Working example with Azure Ad and IdentityServer:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
      .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
            {
                options.ClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>";
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.ClientId ="<ClientId>";
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/";
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
            })
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post since I was having the exact same issue with my Azure App Service. I fixed it by using the exact redirect URL in the error message and adding that to the list of URLs in the app registration.